# Show errors in sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

I have a file `myFile.sql` that contains a list of script to compile :

```
@"Directory\package1.sql"
@"Directory\package2.sql"
@"Directory\package3.sql"
@"Directory\package4.sql"
```

I have the following script:

```
SPOOL Directory\Upgrade.log
@"Directory\myFile.sql"
SPOOL OFF
```

Some packages in `myFile.sql` have errors, but in `Upgrade.log` I do not have the details of the errors, I have the message Warning : `Package body created with compilation errors.`
How can I add the error detail without adding SHOW ERR after each line in `MyFile.sql` ?
In upgrade.log I want have this:

```
Package1 created
Warning Package body created with compilation errors.
**Error detail1**

Package2 created
Warning Package body created with compilation errors.
**Error detail2**
```

I need a hook in **sqlplus** to show error **automatically** after each package creation if there is an error
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to query dictionnary view `USER_ERRORS`, or `ALL_ERRORS`.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/ALL_ERRORS.html#GUID-2237BC4D-F34A-48C5-8181-85426077E65B):

> `ALL_ERRORS` describes the current errors on the stored objects accessible to the current user.

`USER_ERRORS` gives the same information for objects owned by the current user.

Comment: I have the warnig because the packages depends on each other, once the script finishes I recompile all invalid object using EXEC DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(USER,FALSE); what I need is to display the error details after each line in myFile.sql

Comment: @BilelChaouadi: you can filter on column `ATTRIBUTE` to separate warnings from errors.

Comment: I know but I need the warning added after each line, because in my log file I have complile package 1 the warning, package 2 then warning .... I need to add the error detail just after the warning, I want add the datail to log file with the associated line package created

Comment: I need a hook to show errors automatically in sql plus after each compile if there is an error

Comment: The respondents have provided you ways of getting your errors. But still you said "I need the warning added after each line", well ***that is not going to happen***. So choose the best of a bad situation and go with it. What you want will not happen because DIANA (the plsql compiler/interpreter) does not make that available.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle `11.1` onward, you could use the **SQLPlus error logging** feature. You can read more about [SQL*Plus error logging – New feature release 11.1](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/sqlplus-error-logging-new-feature-release-11-1/).

SQL*Plus error logging is set `OFF` by default. So, you need to `set errorlogging on` to use the `SPERRORLOG` table.

**Demo:**

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> desc sperrorlog;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 USERNAME                                           VARCHAR2(256)
 TIMESTAMP                                          TIMESTAMP(6)
 SCRIPT                                             VARCHAR2(1024)
 IDENTIFIER                                         VARCHAR2(256)
 MESSAGE                                            CLOB
 STATEMENT                                          CLOB

SQL> truncate table sperrorlog;

Table truncated.

SQL> set errorlogging on;
SQL> selct * from dual;
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "selct * fr..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> select timestamp, username, script, statement, message from sperrorlog;

TIMESTAMP   USERNAME     STATEMENT           MESSAGE
----------- --------     ------------------  -------
17-APR-2020 SCOTT        selct * from dual;  SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "selct * fr..." - rest of line ignored.
```

Similarly, you can capture **PLS errors** too. They will start with error code `SP`.

Comment: Thank you @Lalit but I want do it automatically, without adding: select timestamp, username, script, statement, message from sperrorlog; because myFile.sql containts more than 300 script to compile.
May be sometihing that reads the file myFile.sql, than loop in each line and add show errors automatically

Comment: `sperrorlog` is automatically created by Oracle, you don't have to do add any column etc. Just set the parameter once that's it.

Comment: But I need to query the sperrorlog  to get the error :( I need this error saved automatically in my log file after each package creation

Comment: @BilelChaouadi In your SQL file, just add one line `SELECT * FROM sperrorlog;` and this will be automatically spooled to your log file. The compilation errors are different from run-time errors. All objects that failed to compile will be in invalid state.

Comment: But if I do this I'll have the log duplicated. when all scripts are compiled, in my log file I have package 1 ctrated, warning: packege created with errors, package 2 ctrated, warning: packege  created with errors .... I want each error added to line associated with the compilation of each script